# Regex: count matches within a certain section of a string

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to count the size of an array within a random set of characters for example;

```
qweqe1wqeqjson=[1,2,5,3]
```

Expression;

```
(?<=json=)?[0-9]
```

Is including the number `1` as a match too. As you can see the kind of solution I am trying to implement will only count matches after `json=`.

Comment: What language or tool do you wish to use? What's your current & expected output?

Comment: Something like `grep -oP '(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|json=\[)\K\d+' <<< "$s" | wc -l`, [demo](https://ideone.com/TnexP9)?

Comment: @dibery Sorry it is basically something I am trying to write in a bash script, the current output counts all matches including the number in the random string of text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked, would you mind explaining the process behind that expression? Just started with regex, Thanks

Comment: If you just started, please note that regexps like the one I posted are quite complex,  use them with care. If you need more explanation, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -oP '(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|json=\[)\K\d+' <<< "$s" | wc -l
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/TnexP9)

The `-oP` means:

- `o` - output matched texts only
- `P` - parse the regex pattern with the PCRE engine

The `(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|json=\[)\K\d+` pattern means:

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|json=\[)` - either the end of the previous successful match and then a `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars or  `json=[` substring
- `\K` - discard all the text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1+ digits

`wc -l` counts the matches.